# 3D perspective not displayed properly if loaded into another animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, loader

For past week I've been trying to make 3D perspective work properly with no luck. I have one "parent" .swf and other "child" .swf loaded into parent. Two of those "child" .swf contain 3D perspective/3D tween. Stage size of parent is 1000x600px, child 700x500px. Loader is pretty simple.

```
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
var mcExternal:MovieClip;
this.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("ani.swf"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfIn);
function swfIn(e:Event):void {
    mcExternal=loader.content as MovieClip; 
}
```

This is how loaded animation looks like: http://andrewk.wz.cz/test/test.html
This is animation before loading: http://andrewk.wz.cz/test/ani.html
Any ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [perspective projection centre](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html#projectionCenter) is off. 
For a 700x500 the default would be at the middle: 350,250
so you can try something like:

```
this.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = new Point(350,250);
```

or set it from the loaded content when it's ready:

```
function swfIn(e:Event):void {
    mcExternal=loader.content as MovieClip; 
    this.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = mcExternal.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter
}
```

Haven't tested myself, but sounds like this could be your issue

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work. I really have no idea how to solve it. Here are source .fla files, for Flash Pro CS5. [link](http://andrewk.wz.cz/test/loader.rar)

Comment: Not as simple as expected because although your document's perspective has some settings(55 degrees fov,centre at 250x250), your tween has others (67.1 degrees fov, centre at 275x200). Easiest option with no coding required is this: 1. go to Document Settings(CMD+J/Ctrl+J) in ani.fla 2. change the dimensions from 700x500 to 1000x600 but **make sure you tick** "Adjust 3D Perspective Angle to preserve current stage projection" which will do all the work for you. Your document will be larger, but you animation will look the same in both ani and loader

Comment: Thanks a lot! This idea occurred to me a while ago but I though that it will cause issues. However I didn't realize that I have all content masked and thus rest of stage even when loaded won't be visible.